# What is Mongolian Trait ? when referring to medical scores of a newborn child in USA

Tags: meaning, medical, contemporary-english, international

What is Mongolian Trait? I have been unable to find the meaning to this My Niece was classified as having Mongolian Trait ..

Comment: We don't know. There is not enough context to tell you anything you don't already know. i.e. what *Mongolian* and *trait* mean.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about the English language per se.

Comment: I have approved an edit by an anonymous user, from the comment left by this user it appears it is the same OP but with a new/different account.  If this is the case, perhaps the user could flag this post, explain they are the original poster and ask to be allowed to edit the post.

Comment: If the existing comments and answers don't answer the question -- I believe they do -- then OP will need to log in as user57879 (using whatever id was used to create and register that account) in order to edit this question. Or use the [contact us](http://english.stackexchange.com/contact) pages to get help from SE on resurrecting that account.

Comment: An anonymous user,  asked to add the following which I'll reproduce verbatim: **"This analysis was found on her birth chart or score hence The day she was born, I assume many tests of her ability and weight also blood type fingerprint were a part of this script She does not have downs syndrome"**. (It wasn't approved by two users because it was suggested by a different account than the OP's)

Comment: When assessing newborns, 'Mongolian skin trait' (or spots) refers to a slight bluish-black tinge to the skin of the lower back, characteristic of central asians or middle easterners.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely, it is a reference to an epicanthic fold, a fold of the upper eye-lid over the lower eyelid on the corners of the eye that are closest to the nose.    Many groups of people, Asians, Native Americans (especially those from Alaska and Canada, have this type of eyelid.  The term is so rarely used nowadays that I almost want to inquire into the age of the clinician who made the observation. The Mongols were the first Asian people known to the Europeans, hence the term.

Comment: Can you cite some references?

Answer (score 0):

The doctor who discovered what we now call Down Syndrome called the people who have it "mongoloids" because he thought they looked Asian around the eyes.  That term is now considered racist and inaccurate, so it is no longer in common use, but it's possible it might still be used in some places.

Comment: In no way should "mongoloid trait," an anthropological term, be considered diagnostic of trisomy 21, or Down syndrome.

Comment: Agreed, but the use of the term is a matter of historical record.  My mother's brother had Down's Syndrome, and "Mongoloid" is what he was called in 1950's America.

Comment: Yes, according to a search of the archives of the journal Pediatrics (US), the term was used medically from at least the early 1930s, peaked in the 1950s and had died out by 1975.  According to current medical publication standards it appears that "trisomy 21" and "Down syndrome" are equally used.  One additional note, there is no apostrophe-s.  According to current usage we have Lou Gehrig's disease, because Gehrig had the disorder, and Down syndrome, because J.L. Down first described the disorder.